# Are there any treasure vaults to break into?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

While on my travels in Skyrim i found one place (Markarth) which reminded me of Vivec from Morrowind, in the sense that there was a secured area with the possibility of gold and loot behind locked doors.  Which made me wonder...has anyone located any vaults like we had in Vivec?  Basically im trying to figure out if a vault exists similar to the redoran vault and hllalu vault.  I remember being so stoked to find a room that was full of gold jewels and armor.

Comment: I think there's one in the Treasury House I think. I robbed it before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The closest thing I've found to this so far is the

> [Dwarven Storeroom](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarven_Storeroom)

It's got a couple chests with leveled loot, a battleaxe with a random enchantment, lots of Ingots, and things you can smelt into Ingots. Part is protected by an Apprentice lock, and part by an Expert lock.

Comment: was hoping for atleast more input from others but thanks...i WILL be checking this out

Answer (score 11):

While I haven't come across any vaults, just a reminder that certain dungeons have "treasure rooms" where there are massive amounts of loot behind a locked door:

[image]

In the above room I found the following: an enchanted glass bow, a quiver of dwarven arrows, a plethora of potions, three coin purses, a book with a skill increase, a few gems, and some alchemy ingredients. Also, my sixth Berenziah stone was on one of the shelves just hanging out for me to grab.

So while it's not a secure area, it might be the next best thing. Mainly, just a friendly reminder - always check behind locked doors in dungeons. They are definitely worth the trouble!

Comment: i do need to do a better job...

Answer (score 2):

Go to Pinewatch near Falkreath, literally next door to Lakeview Manor on the hearthfire add-on, there's a hidden door in the basement of the house and at the end there's a room with a hell of a lot of gems gold and ores etc, and its only bandits inside so nothing too hard to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

The Biggest Skyrim Treasure!

1. Download the Dragonborn expansion pack.
2. Reach level 36 before embarking on this quest; you won’t be able to start it without reaching this level first. Some sources say you actually must be level 38, but as we were level 40 when we started the quest, we have no way of finding out the correct level. Please let me know in the comments if you were level 36 or 37 and it let you start the quest.
3. Head to Solstheim. To get there, go into a town and wait until you’re attacked by cultists. Kill them and read their notes after searching their dead bodies. Catch the boat to Solstheim from the docks outside Windhelm.
4. Read the Deathbrand book. These can be found in various locations, including the Great Hall in Skaal Village. The easiest place to find it is probably The Retching Netch inn in Raven Rock, which is the town you arrive in by boat from Windhelm. It’s on a bookshelf in one of the bedrooms.
5. Find the pirates guarding the chest with the Deathbrand armour Helm in it near Haknir’s Shoal. One of them will have a treasure map.
6. Find all the other pieces of the armour by heading to locations marked on the map. The last chest will contain the key to Gyldenhul Barrow.
7. Visit Raven Rock again and talk to the smith Glover Mallory. He’ll send you on a quest to retrieve an Ancient Nord Pickaxe. Once you’ve got it and return to him, he’ll let you keep it. (Unless you already have an Ancient Nord Pickaxe)
8. Head to Gyldenhul Barrow in the North East of Solstheim.
9. Use the Ancient Nord Pickaxe to mine the Stahlrim in the room. One of the pieces of rock will give way to a hidden treasure room.
10. Enjoy your loot.
11. Continue through the doors ahead to enter a burial chamber. Pick up the sword from the skeleton at the far end of the room.
12. Kill all the ghosts. (A LOT of ghosts)
13. Pick up the other sword from Hankir Death-Brand once he’s dead (again).
14. Enjoy living the life of a pirate with your two new swords: Bloodscythe and Soulrender.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is go to Septimus Signus Outpost and start the daedric quest ["discerning the transmundane"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane). You will be given an attunement sphere and a lexicon. [Alftand](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alftand) has a lot of awesome loot and at least a dozen chests. They are usually locked, bring enough lockpicks.

After you finish Alftand you will use the sphere to gain access to [Blackreach](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blackreach). (*Make sure you have a pickaxe*) Take a long walk around and mine everything you find. I got a lot of gems. There are also a lot more chests in Blackreach.

Comment: Hi Christian welcome to the site. I cleaned up your answer a bit and added some links to a wiki. Don't worry about others editing your posts, it is how we roll. (Do note, this is a question and answer site, not a: This awesome thing happend in my game site). So keep the personal stories to a minimum. (I do like some personal stories though, it makes it less bland. But make sure your answer contains a larger answer part :) ).

Answer (score -1):

I have found an invisible chest full of all sorts of junk. It is to your left outside of solitude.

If you go there you may see a cat that sells stuff also known as the "caravans". Look next to him and look for a purple or gray scar looking mark on the ground. It is very small so you will have to sneak. Go straight very slowly and it should say "search chest".

Answer (score -1):

I have found an invisable chest full of all sorts of junk it is to your left outside of solitude if you go you may see a cat that sells stuff also known as the "caravans". Look next to him and look for a purple or gray scar looking Mark on the ground it is very small so you will have to sneak,anyways,go straight very slowly and it should say "search chest" but it is not a treasure vault...

Answer (score -2):

With the dragonborn DLC there is one dungeon in Solstheim that has at least 1000 gold and some gems in it, but not much else.

Comment: Is it a vault that you have to break into? This question is not about places to get rich, it's about the fun of breaking into a treasure vault.

Answer (score -2):

Do the deathbrand and head to Gyldenhul Barrow. In the second room having no enemies to fight there's a room full of gold. (About 8000 Septims) Just lying on the floor with a couple of chests.

Answer (score -2):

I know exactly what you are looking for i also wanted to find something "like" that... A full on treasure room that you are looking for you won't find in skyrim no... Not without mods... But the closest thing i could find to what you are looking for is Fahlbtharz.... Essentially the entire dwemer ruin is a form of a vault since there is moderate loot gear ect all along the path of it.... The only problem with this is you need the Dragonborn DLC since Fahlbtharz is on the island of Solstheim that requires the DLC... The only other thing i can think of for you is to go to "Nexus Mod Mannager's" website and look for treasure room mods... Almost all Castle mods have treasure rooms but a lot of them are empty... But a "breaking and entering + looting" treasure vault does not exist in Skyrim other than the Treasury Room in Markarth.... And in Blackreach some item rooms. Hope I helped in answering your question.

Answer (score -3):

In Lodestar, by the smelter, there is a mine. Right next to that, there are two rocks. Go bewtwen them and there will be a chest full of amazing stuff. It is random, so you won't necessarily get what I got, but you can find great armor and about 40 lockpicks in there.

Comment: I don't think this quite answers the question.

Comment: Not a treasure vault in the sense described in the question.